# Hot to properly sort mixed string/numbers data in proper order

Tags: javascript

Here is an object I want to sort by code field like: a1111, b1111, 22222:

```
const myObj = [{code: 'b1111'}, {code: '2222'}, {code: 'a1111'}]
```

and my sort function:

```
const sortData = (data) => {
    return data.sort((a, b) => {  
        return a.code < b.code ? -1 : a.code > b.code ? 1 : 0;
      });
  };

console.log(sortData(myObj))
```

I expect to get data sorted this way (any characters first then digits):

```
[ { code: 'a1111' }, { code: 'b1111' }, { code: '2222' } ]
```

but getting

```
[ { code: '2222' }, { code: 'a1111' }, { code: 'b1111' } ]
```

so how do I fix sort function?

Comment: See the linked question and [these others](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+sort+array+of+strings+with+numbers+and+letters).

Comment: I do not see exact answer to my question.. Could you please run my code and see the issue?

Comment: how do you want `a2222, 1111` to be sorted?

Comment: whatever starts with letter goes first sorted.. then only number items also sorted. So: a1111, b1111, 2222

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split `code` by a regex and compare accordingly. If you want extended code page support, use `Intl.Collator` in the last comparison of the alpha chars.

```js
const collator = Intl.Collator('en', {numeric:true});

const myObj = [{code: 'b1111'}, {code: '2222'}, {code: 'a1111'}];

const regex = /(\D*)(\d+)/;
myObj.sort(({code:a}, {code:b}) => {
  a = a.match(regex);
  b = b.match(regex);
  if(a[1] === b[1] || !a[1] && !b[1]) return a[2] - b[2];
  if(!a[1] && b[1]) return 1;
  if(!b[1] && a[1]) return -1;
  return a[1] > b[1] ? 1 : -1;
});

console.log(...myObj);
```

Comment: this is it.. Thank you Mr. Nenashev